# .NET Maui, iOS only SocketException No route to host

Tags: c#, network-programming, maui

I have a simple Maui application (.NET7) which communicates with a local network server. I'm testing it using Android and iPhone. The code is simple:

```
TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
await client.ConnectAsync(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.3.10"), 12345);
```

or another code

```
Ping ping = new Ping();
await ping.SendPingAsync(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.3.10"));
```

In both case the result is `SocketException (65): No route to host`. This happens on iPhone only. On Android it works fine.

My Android phone IP is 192.168.3.45 and iPhone IP is 192.168.3.170. Both are on the same network as the server.

In the project I even added the following to the Info.plist:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsLocalNetworking</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

On my iPhone 13 mini, iOS 16.3.1 I can see the server using *Fing - Network Scanner* and its *Device Discovery*. I'm able to Ping it.

[Edit]
I created a sample project to reproduce the issue. Connect to your local iPhone device and click the button and in the debugger (`OnCounterClicked` method) see the exception thrown.
https://github.com/CsabaStupak/MauiLocNetIssue.git

What is interesting that on some iPhone this is not reproducible. According to https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/12731 maybe this is an iOS 16 issue.

Any idea what could be the problem?
Thanks :-)

Comment: You need to get ping working between two machines before trying to make a TCP connection.  Usually the issue is a mask setting when you have two machines on same network.  Try from cmd.exe >IPCONFIG/ALL which will give the masks and network interfaces.  One machine may be using IP4 and the other IP6.

Comment: I'm able to see my server from iPhone - at least the Network Scanner finds it and I can scan for its ports too. Only my Maui application has this issue and only on iPhone.

Comment: See if following helps : https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211227?force_isolation=true

Comment: Unfortunately this did not help. I even created a simple (empty) Maui application with the given code. First time it launches the Grant access to local network message appears on my iPhone what I allowed (I can see in the settings it has local network access on), however I receive the same exception. The same ping code works if I try to ping 8.8.8.8 address. So this is apparently a local network access issue - somehow iPhone ignores the fact that I granted access to the local network...

Comment: It is the mask on default route.  Every Ethernet device has a default IP with a mask which is the port that goes to the gateway.  The mask on this route should have a mask of 0.0.0.0 so nothing gets blocked.  On windows from cmd.exe if you type >IPCONFIG/ALL.  A lot of machines I think are configured wrong according to what I was taught in Graduate School.maui default route

Comment: See following : https://devicetests.com/how-to-find-the-default-gateway-on-android?force_isolation=true  Either change the mask on the IP or the default gateway.  I would make it the same as the working IPHONE.

Comment: I do not think this is a mask or gateway. If it would be that case then the iPhone app: Fing - Network Scanner would not find my server. On my iPhone the Wifi settings shows it is correct - my IP=192.168.3.170, mask=255.255.255.0 and gateway/router=192.168.3.1, my "server" on Windows machine shows me similar setting IP=192.168.3.1 the mask and the gateway is the same as on my iPhone. On my Android device it is the same as well ofc the IP differs (see above).

Comment: Ping is ARP protocol with a ARP Request and an ARP Response.  If you don't have a route is usually means the masks are not correct or hardware isn't working.  I've seen cases where ping fails due to routing loops and duplicate IP addresses.   You have a small network.  You could have a bad cable or broken hardware.  Usually I draw a map of the network on paper and then test what works and don't work with PING to isolate issue.  check ARP table in windows from cmd.exe sometimes helps >ARP -A which will give the IP address seen by machine in the last hour.  After 1 hour an entry is removed.

Comment: Could you explain why a different application running on my iPhone can ping my server and my maui application running on the same iPhone can't ping?
What I'm trying to say that it can NOT be a mask, gateway/router issue nor server configuration. Note: I'm a network administrator so I have pretty good understanding what these settings mean :-) IMHO this is somehow related to iPhone and how it grants access to resources for application. Apparently in my case I do not have access and the exception I receive is probably a misleading - it has nothing to do to "no route".

Comment: Maui may be setup as a virtual machine with a different IP.  Not sure.  Didn't realize the issue was on same Phone, was thinking different machine.  See if following is useful : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/android/device/setup?force_isolation=true&view=net-maui-7.0#connecting-over-wifi

Comment: That is a description how to connect an Android to VS. I already connected Android and iPhone to VS for debugging. Moreover I have problem with iPhone.

Comment: Not really.  It is how to configure IP to connect from Linux to Windows.  You said IPhone worked, only the MAUI app did not work.  I think Maui is a Virtual Machine with a different IP.  I've seen issues like this where Virtual Linux was installed on Windows machine and Windows could not connect to the Linux Virtual machine due to the Linux being in a different subnet. If you have a sniffer you can ping from Maui and find what IP it is using.

Comment: did you ever resolve this?  I am getting the same error trying to use RSSDP to scan the network for SSDP devices.  Works on Android, but get "SocketException (65): No route to host" on IOS

Answer (score 0):

Well, suddenly it started to work - how? It is a miracle :-O

I was pretty desperate with this so I changed several things at once and not sure which helped:

- my buildleId was something like sk.company.appname so I changed it to com.company.appname
- switched to VS for Mac and continued the development there, I had trouble to publish my app from Windows VS
- I recreated my certificates (it is a nightmare)
- Updated my VS, .NET for Mac

and since that it works...

Answer (score 0):

I want to add another solution in case anyone else runs into this error message.  I was running into the same thing while using RSSDP on the iPHONE (SocketException (65): No route to host).  SSDP is a multicast protocol and Apple requires a special entitlement for that.

So, if you are getting "SocketException (65): No route to host" and using a multicast protocol, follow the links below to request the special entitlement from Apple (which took about a week for us).

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/entitlements/com_apple_developer_networking_multicast

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/663271